# Prevent VS Code intellisense suggestion boxes from consuming up/down arrows

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When I type "std::" in VS Code with Intellisense active, a dropdown appears with suggested completions. Then, pressing the down key will cycle through the dropdown. But I don't want to browse through the dropdown with my arrow keys; I want to move to the next line of code. Is there a way to make arrow keys ignore the dropdown without disabling dropdowns entirely?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add these to your `keybindings.json` or find the `selectNextSuggestion` and `selectPrevSuggestion` commands in the `Ketboard Shortcuts` and disable them:

```json
{
  "key": "down",
  "command": "-selectNextSuggestion",
  "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus || suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus && !suggestWidgetHasFocusedSuggestion"
},
{
  "key": "up",
  "command": "-selectPrevSuggestion",
  "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus || suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus && !suggestWidgetHasFocusedSuggestion"
}
// {
//   "key": "down",
//   "command": "your other command here",
//   "when": "suggestWidgetMultipleSuggestions && suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus || suggestWidgetVisible && textInputFocus && !suggestWidgetHasFocusedSuggestion"
// }
```

The first disables the default <kbd>DownArrow</kbd> action when a suggest panel is open and the second makes the <kbd>DownArrow</kbd> do something else in that situation.  You don't need the second keybinding since you only want the default action once the special `selectNextSuggestion` is disabled.

By the way, even with this these keybindings removed you can still use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down</kbd> to move the selection in the suggest widget.

Comment: If you go to preferences > open keyboard shortcuts, editing/removing shortcuts will automatically edit this file with what you need. Also, try the command "showNextParameterHint" to disable the down arrow on those as well. I guess we are the only ones left who don't use the mouse for everything.

Comment: Brilliant. For up arrow obviously use "up" and "-selectPrevSuggestion"

Comment: Sadly, this solution seems to have broken, because I have it in my keybindings.json but now the cursed popup is reacting to down-arrow presses again! Anyone know the updated magic incantations?

Comment: @Rennex See the edited answer for the fix.